# What does multiplication mean in terms of $2\times \pi$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If your answer is multiplication is nothing but all about addition i.e.,
$a \times b = \underbrace {a + \cdots + a}_{b} = \underbrace{b+\cdots +b}_a$

then in multiplication of $2 \times \pi$ how will you write $2$ as $\pi$ times?

**Where $\pi$ is an irrational number.**

Comment: In this particular case you can actually do it. $$2\times \pi=\pi + \pi$$

Comment: A better question would be about the product of two irrationals.

Comment: You could see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU) (from about a minute in), as it explains one way to think about multiplication that doesn't have the problem you're describing. The video itself has the focus of explaining exponentials (and specifically $e^{i\pi}$), but the framework helps a lot here too.

Comment: You can also ask, what the meaning of the multiplication with two rational numbers $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\in\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$. Or the meaning of the multiplication of two negative integers. For these elementary questions, you need to study the construction of the numbers.

Comment: $e^{\log 2 + \log \pi}$.

Comment: @Naive Multiplication follow commutative property. Therefore if you are trying to write $2\times \pi  = \pi + \pi$ then tell me how to write $2$ as $\pi$ times?

Comment: You could always define the product of two real numbers $a$ and $b$ as $$\int_0^a\int_0^b1\,dy\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication can be defined on [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) via iterative application of the addition operation. This definition (probably) makes no sense for other objects then natural numbers.

However, multiplication can also be reasonably defined on other domains, such as integers or reals, and they usually satisfy similar properties, such as $2\times x=x+x$. A formal definition of real numbers can be done in some axiomatic theories, such as [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) -- usually you first define integers and rationals as certain pairs, and then reals as [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut), and then you have to carefully define what $\times$ and $+$ means.

The more formal you want to be, the more complicated it becomes. But it can be done.